# The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error whenever making a build for the Windows platform.

```
The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class. This is not supported: Base(MonoBehaviour) speed
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

The problem is that it is not showing which script has a problem? The error is not showing in the editor but it showing whenever I try to build and it failing my build.

Comment: it looks like both your base class and a inherited one contain a field with name `speed`. Hard to say for us which class it is if yourself can't tell already.. is this the full output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have said this error occurring whenever I try to build for windows platform

```
The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class. This is not supported: Base(MonoBehaviour) speed
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I found that I was rewriting the build on the same location while the output log text file of the build was open. After closing the output log file of last build, I am able to successfully build.

Answer (score 2):

Bumping the version did it for me

Project Settings -> Player -> Version